# VSCode Java not linting or autocompleting local variables but is autocompleting java shortcuts such as 'sysout'

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, lint, macos-catalina

Have little idea what caused this and I am unsure of what to try next. Basic reinstalls and restarts have not worked. As the photo explains, the variable 'simulateDroppedMessage' does not autocomplete but 'public_static_method' does. Furthermore, the missing semicolon on line 3 is not linted. Running Catalina but not keen on updating due to other software not being updated yet. Any advice appreciated

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) provides live linting and intellisense. Try [reset VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code) and reinstall extension. See if it helps.

Comment: public_static_method are client side code snippet which is hard coded(see [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/blob/b4f8b07d774acb17bee19f3b06f4d0364a72c682/snippets/java.json#L68)). So they are always available. According to your description, seems that the java language server is not ready or not working properly. Is there any suspicious errors in the server log? You can see it by triggering `Java: Open Java Language Server Log File`